# JMSI18nRoutingBundle symfony2 create the routing tranlations

Tags: php, symfony

I use JMSI18nRoutingBundle in symfony2.

I read all the docs --> http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSI18nRoutingBundle

and used the    3. Scenario  in my config:

```
jms_i18n_routing:
    default_locale: en
    locales: [en, he]
    strategy: custom
    hosts:
        en: example.com
        he: example.co.il
    redirect_to_host: false
```

I even tried to use   2. Scenario

that will simply add a prefix for the url for other languages.

as I see my problem is that when I enter to the url:  example.co.il

it says that it cant find a route for it.
When I add this->
    options: { i18n: false }

to the route, it works  (this is for "Leaving routes untranslated")

as I see that simply means that the routes for the "he" local simply doesn't exist.

An ideas how do I implement it?

as requested, here is my router:debug -->
(I added just a part of it, because it was very long)

```
he_en__RG__site_base_homepage            ANY    ANY    ANY  /
he__RG__site_base_homepage               ANY    ANY    ANY  /
en__RG__site_base_homepage               ANY    ANY    ANY  /
he_en__RG__site_base_about               ANY    ANY    ANY  /about
he__RG__site_base_about                  ANY    ANY    ANY  /about
en__RG__site_base_about                  ANY    ANY    ANY  /about
he_en__RG__site_base_contact             GET    ANY    ANY  /contact
he__RG__site_base_contact                GET    ANY    ANY  /contact
en__RG__site_base_contact                GET    ANY    ANY  /contact
he_en__RG__site_base_contact_verify      POST   ANY    ANY  /contact
he__RG__site_base_contact_verify         POST   ANY    ANY  /contact
en__RG__site_base_contact_verify         POST   ANY    ANY  /contact
he_en__RG__terms_of_use                  ANY    ANY    ANY  /terms
he__RG__terms_of_use                     ANY    ANY    ANY  /terms
en__RG__terms_of_use                     ANY    ANY    ANY  /terms
```

Comment: what says `php app/console router:debug`?

Comment: just added a part of it Pazi

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

php bin/console translation:extract de --enable-extractor=jms_i18n_routing  --dir=./src --output-dir=./app/Resources/translations

at the console already? Exchange 'de' to your needs. After clearing cache it worked for me.

PLease use with care as it deleted some Translations in my messages.de.yml file.

Answer (score -1):

It states in the manual:

Whenever a pattern is matched to a different host’s locale a redirect is used, unless redirect_to_host is set to false, in which case a ResourceNotFoundException is thrown which typically results in a 404 error.

So this is normal behaviour if you put redirect_to_host to false

Comment: yes I know that, but why those routes don't exist? how do I create them them?

Comment: The routes do exists as your dumb shows. Apparently the router:dumb doesn't show the full path including the domain. Please accept my answer and post a new question if you will.

Comment: sorry, but what should I accept? what you said is known. How do I set the routes for the "he" site version?