# Translate a certain part of the URI with JMSI18nRoutingBundle in Symfony 2.3.x

Tags: symfony, routes, translation, locale, symfony-2.3

I have a problem using the JMSi18nRoutungBundle from Johannes Schmitt in **Symfony 2.3.x**. It's a 'little' like in this post: [JMSI18nRoutingBundle symfony2 create the routing tranlations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18033627/jmsi18nroutingbundle-symfony2-create-the-routing-tranlations)

I followed the instructions for installing and configuring the bundle and (almost) everything is working fine so far. Now I want to use the bundle like in "**Scenario 1**" from the bundle-doc: http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSI18nRoutingBundle/master/configuration#scenario-prefixing-all-routes-with-the-locale

So I setted up the jms_i18n_routing.yml like this: (*the %locale%-value comes from the config.yml where jms_i18n_routing.yml is included*)

```
jms_i18n_routing:
    default_locale: %locale%
    locales: [%locale%, en]         # for more languages, add them to this array
    strategy: prefix
```

And the route in the **routing.xml** like this:

```
<route id="web_public_contact" pattern="/kontakt">
    <default key="_controller">WebPublicBundle:Contact:index</default>
</route>
```

When I open the contact-page (**after** clearing the cache! ;-) the url looks like:

- app_dev.php/de/kontakt

This is quite perfect! But when I switch to the english version the url looks like:

- app_dev.php/en/kontakt

Ok. It works and shows the content in english. But now I want the url for the 'english version' looks like this (...like in "**Scenario 1**"):

- app_dev.php/en/contact

But **THAT** doesn't work.
How can I 'translate' the part "kontakt" for the english-route to "contact"??

Here is the output of **router:debug** for the contact-page:

```
de__RG__web_public_contact       ANY    ANY    ANY  /de/kontakt
en__RG__web_public_contact       ANY    ANY    ANY  /en/kontakt
```

I tried it for several day now... Read all the docs, tuts and posts I found about this issue but nothing worked for me so far.

Maybe there is someone out there, who can give a little "push in the right direction"!?

HAPPY NEW YEAR & thanks a lot (I know... for "nothing so far". But for ME it's a 'duty' to say "thank you" in advance! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if you still need help but need to run command (in your project directory):

```
php app/console translation:extract en --enable-extractor=jms_i18n_routing  --dir=./src --output-dir=./app/Resources/translations
```

This will create /app/Resources/translations/routes.en.xliff file where you can set "kontakt" translation for English - in this case you set "contact" for "kontakt" route

Of course you can do that for other languages (including de) if you want - just change en in command to other language and change translation in new routes.[lang].xliff

If it won't work you should probably clear cache:

```
php app/console cache:clear
```

Hope it will help you